# Function that append checksum to an integer

Tags: php, security, cryptography, checksum

I have a function `gen_seq` that return a random generated integer of length **n**

e.g.

```
gen_seq(5); // return a randomly generated int of length n, e.g. 12345
```

Now, I want a simple function that in append the checksum the end of function

```
get_seq_with_checksum(5); // return 12345[28]
is_valid_seq(n); // check if a given string is valid according to the input function
```

1. What would be a good fit algorithm pairs for function `get_seq_with_checksum` & `is_valid_seq`?

Answer (score 0):

A simple parity word should do pretty much what you're after – XOR each byte of the message together to create the checksum, and verify similarly.